# Microsoft azure ssh connection to VM keeps dropping

Tags: azure, ssh

I am connecting to virtual machine (ubuntu 14.04) hosted on Microsoft Azure using ssh. My problem is that my connection drops every couple minutes (same period) and I need to reconnect. This is not related to internet connection because it doesn't drop. I tried logging from different pc's, it's all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this is caused by inactivity: see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-ssh-server-connection-drops-out-after-few-or-n-minutes-of-inactivity.html

To summarize, an ssh connection is sometimes dropped after a few minutes.

From the OpenSSH man page:

> This is usually the result of a packet filter or NAT device timing out your TCP connection due to inactivity. For security, reason most enterprises only use SSH protocol version 2. This problem only occurred with version 2.

You can try following the instructions in that article.